# Perl: Separate log for each device & convert IP to hostname from the log filenames

Tags: perl, logging, cisco, logfile, juniper-network-connect

I have created a perl that telnet to multiple switches. My code is generates only one log file output for multiple Cisco switches.

What should I do to create separate log file for each device status(include telnet failure)?
And how could I convert IP to hostname from the log filenames?

Desired output log files one by one, hostname1.log, hostname2.log, hostname3.log......so on and so forth.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Cisco;

my $username="danny";
my $pass="1234";

open (OUTPUT, ">intstatus.log" );
open (IP, "ip.txt") or die $!;

for my $line (<IP>) {
chomp $line;
$line =~ s/\t+//;
print $line, "\n";
SWTELNET($line); # pass $line as the argument to SWTELNET
}
sub SWTELNET {

my $host = shift; # $host is set to the first argument passed in from the above loop
my $t = Net::Telnet::Cisco -> new (
Host => $host,
Prompt => '/(?m:^(?:[\w.\/]+\:)?[\w.-]+\s?(?:\(config[^\)]*\))?\s?[\$#>]\s?(?:\(enable\))?\s*$)/',
Timeout => 6,
Errmode => 'return',
) or die "connect failed: $!";

if ($t->login($username,$pass)) {
$t->autopage;
$t->always_waitfor_prompt;

my @supenv=$t->cmd("show ip int br");
my @output = ();
print OUTPUT "$host\n@supenv\n";
 }
}
close(IP);
close(OUTPUT);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any telnet devices to test with, but this should at least get you most of the way. It uses `gethostbyaddr()` from [Socket](http://perldoc.perl.org/Socket.html) to try to resolve the IP back to a hostname (and falls back to using the IP as hostname if the name can't be found). It also uses the proper three-argument form of [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) with lexical file handles (as opposed to bareword handles), and it opens a new log file for writing in the format `hostname.log` for each host found in the input file.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Net::Telnet::Cisco;
use Socket;

my $username="danny";
my $pass="1234";

open my $infile, '<', "ip.txt" or die $!;

for my $ip (<$infile>) {
    chomp $ip;
    $ip =~ s/\t+//;

    # resolve IP to hostname if possible

    my $host = gethostbyaddr(inet_aton($ip), AF_INET);

    $host = $ip if ! $host;

    SWTELNET($host);
}

close $infile;

sub SWTELNET {

    my $host = shift;

    my $t = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(
        Host => $host,
        Prompt => '/(?m:^(?:[\w.\/]+\:)?[\w.-]+\s?(?:\(config[^\)]*\))?\s?[\$#>]\s?(?:\(enable\))?\s*$)/',
        Timeout => 6,
        Errmode => 'return',
    ) or die "connect failed: $!";

    if ($t->login($username,$pass)) {
        $t->autopage;
        $t->always_waitfor_prompt;

        my @supenv=$t->cmd("show ip int br");

        # no need to manually close the file after, as it'll happen
        # automatically as soon as the scope ends

        open my $wfh, '>', "$host.log";
        print $wfh "$host\n@supenv\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I can create separate log file for each device status. However log files are still indicated by IP. The program stop running and does not go automatically to the next device when telnet failure occurs, please kindly advise? Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, do you have reverse DNS set up for the IP addresses you're connecting to? If not, you'll be stuck with the IP. As far as not progressing with errors, it'd help if you specified what errors you get. Also, have you tried reading the documentation or perhaps try an `eval` where it is failing?